# Find the average winning size.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> When a slot machine is pressed, a computer randomly chooses a point from a rectangle ($X = 2.05$, $Y = 1.57$). The winning size is $25$ times greater than the distance between the chosen point and the rectangle's center. Find the average winning size.

I have no idea how to solve it. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  what is the center of the rectangle?  Given a point $(x,y)$ what is the distance to the center?  The win for that point is $25$ times this.  Integrate the win over the rectangle and divide by the area of the rectangle.